# Save the Word file with Specific Text in the Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA and tried to work on a code that can save multiple pages of word documents as a separate PDF.

I am not only struggling with the File name, currently, it is saving with Page no but I require it to be a specific field from a Word document.

I have added the screenshot of my word doc and the name of the file should be  "User ID" and "Reminder 1 ( this is fixed value)".doc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLxC1.png)

This is my code

```
Sub SaveAsSeparatePDFs()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFolder As Variant
    Dim xStart, xEnd As Integer
    On Error GoTo lbl
    Set xDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xFolder = xDlg.SelectedItems(1)
    xStart = CInt(InputBox("Select Start Page No", "Information"))
    xEnd = CInt(InputBox("Select End Page No", "Information"))
    If xStart <= xEnd Then
        For I = xStart To xEnd
            ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
                xFolder & "\Reminder 1" & I & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
                wdExportFromTo, From:=I, To:=I, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
                IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=False, CreateBookmarks:= _
                wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
                BitmapMissingFonts:=False, UseISO19005_1:=False
        Next
    End If
    Exit Sub
lbl:
    MsgBox "Enter right page number", vbInformation, "ERROR"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to know for sure from your screenshot which paragraph your ID# is in. It appears to be in the 3rd paragraph, in which case:

```
Sub SaveAsSeparatePDFs()
    Dim I As Long, Rng As Range
    Dim xDlg As FileDialog, xFolder As Variant
    Dim xStart As Long, xEnd As Long
    Set xDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xFolder = xDlg.SelectedItems(1)
    On Error GoTo lbl
    xStart = CInt(InputBox("Select Start Page No", "Information"))
    xEnd = CInt(InputBox("Select End Page No", "Information"))
    If xStart <= xEnd Then
        For I = xStart To xEnd
            With ActiveDocument
                Set Rng = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=I)
                Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
                .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=xFolder & "\" & _
                    Split(Split(Rng.Paragraphs(3).Range.Text, vbCr)(0), ": ")(1) & _
                    " Reminder 1.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
                    OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportFromTo, _
                    From:=I, To:=I, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, _
                    KeepIRM:=False, CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, _
                    DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:=False, UseISO19005_1:=False
            End With
        Next
    End If
    Exit Sub
lbl:
    MsgBox "Enter right page number", vbInformation, "ERROR"
End Sub
```

If it's not the 3rd paragraph, change the '3' in '.Paragraphs(3)' to suit.

Comment: Dear Sir, A big thank you.. It worked to an extent, just a small help.. need space between Name & Reminder 1.pdf. request your help.

Comment: Surely you could do at least that much??? See updated answer.

Comment: This is now not working.. my requirement is to save multiple pages as PDF with specific name.. however your code is saving only 1 document where the name comes from 1st page (paragraph 3) and the contents in format comes from the last page no inputted

Comment: Evidently you changed something else. Putting a space where I did has no effect whatsoever on the rest of the code.

Comment: I understand  but your initial code only didn;t work,

Comment: The code works for me when the correct paragraph # is identified and the document is as described. As I said in my answer, though «*It's impossible to know for sure from your screenshot which paragraph your ID# is in*» and «*If it's not the 3rd paragraph, change the '3' in '.Paragraphs(3)' to sui*t». Of course, if this document is the product of a mailmerge - which you haven't said - then it's likely to have Section breaks and every Section's page numbering will start at 1 - so the code won't work as written.